# trouble passing parameters, cached values getting passed in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am generating and adding list items dynamically by parsing xml data.

Code looks like

```
    $(document).ready(function(){       

    var xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><contactDetails xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><user><name>Abc </name><phone>1234</phone></user><user><name>Xyz</name><phone>45678</phone></user></contactDetails>",

    xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
    $xml = $( xmlDoc),
    $title = $xml.find("user").each(function(){
    name = $(this).find("name").text();
    phone = $(this).find("phone").text();
    txt = '<li><a  href="#details?phone='+escape(phone)+'">' + name +'</a></li>';   
    $('#myul').append(txt);     
    });     

    $('#myul').listview('refresh');
    });
```

where details is an internal page

```
<div id="details" data-role="page" >
<div data-role="header">
    <a data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-icon="back">back</a>
    <h1>Contacts</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content" >    

</div>
```

**Expected behaviour:**

on click of a list item, its details needs be shown on other page.
phone number in this case.

**Problem:**

After pressing back button, value of last clicked item gets passed on clicking an item.

Comment: added data-ajax="false" to get rid of the problem. but i am looking for a best approach of passing parameters to other internal page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added `data-ajax="false"` to get rid of the problem